# How to have a different color for each ranking in your table

Tags: javascript, html, ranking

I have four Ranking in my table and I would like to have a different color for each Ranking and
possible bold each letter.  I thought I could add <style= color: red;> but that just changes the color for all the Ranking with the same color.  How can I add a different color to each individual ranking only not the description.  Been trying for a few days with no solution.

```
 - Y = yellow  R = Red  G = Green   B = Blue

JavaScript:

    const RANK_TO_DESCRIPTION_MAPPING = {
        "R": "There is a release site/generator at or within 500 feet of the target property",
        "Y": "There is a release site/generator within 500 feet and 1,000 feet of the target property",
        "G": "There are no known release sites/generators within 1,000 feet of the target property",
        "B": "There is a drinking water well at or within 500 feet of the target property",
    }

HTML:

<div class="mb-2">
<div class="results-section">
     <div class="report-wrapper">
        <div class="col-auto">
                <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-light">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="report-header" colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">Report</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> Address: </th> 
                    <td id="proposed-address">  </td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> Latitude: </th>    
                    <td id="proposed-lat"> </td>    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> Longitude: </th>   
                    <td id="proposed-lng"> </td>    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> Rank: </th>
                    <td id="proposed-rank"> </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th> Description: </th>
                    <td id="proposed-description"> </td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr>
                     <th> NHDES OneStop Website: </th>
                     <td id="proposed-website"> </td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>  
     </div>
</div>          
</div>
```

Comment: This is a job for css. Use classes and to make it easy, make the class the same as your current identifier (Y,R,G,B)

Comment: Use CSS classes for each of the rankings, for example `ranking-r`, `ranking-y`, etc.

Comment: Do I also need to add these classes to my html code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try out this**

```css
 **CSS**

#proposed-address{
    background-color: red;
}
#proposed-lat{
    background-color: aqua;
}

#proposed-lng{
    background-color: gold;
}
#proposed-rank{
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Tutorial</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <div class="results-section">
                 <div class="report-wrapper">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                            <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-light">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="report-header" colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">Report</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th> Address: </th> 
                                <td id="proposed-address">XYZ Address</td>   
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th> Latitude: </th>    
                                <td id="proposed-lat">Xyz Latitude</td>    
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th> Longitude: </th>   
                                <td id="proposed-lng">XYZ Longitude</td>    
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th> Rank: </th>
                                <td id="proposed-rank"> XYZ Rank</td>
                            </tr>
            
                            <tr>
                                <th> Description: </th>
                                <td id="proposed-description"> </td>
                            </tr>
                        
                            <tr>
                                 <th> NHDES OneStop Website: </th>
                                 <td id="proposed-website"> </td>
                            </tr>
            
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                    </div>  
                 </div>
            </div>          
            </div>
        
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for css. Use classes and to make it easy, make the class the same as your current identifier (Y,R,G,B). For clarity, I removed the other HTML. For fun I added a rotating script to change the color every second, but that part (the `setInterval` part is absolutely not necessary.

```js
//  - Y = yellow  R = Red  G = Green   B = Blue

const RANK_TO_DESCRIPTION_MAPPING = {
  "R": "There is a release site/generator at or within 500 feet of the target property",
  "Y": "There is a release site/generator within 500 feet and 1,000 feet of the target property",
  "G": "There are no known release sites/generators within 1,000 feet of the target property",
  "B": "There is a drinking water well at or within 500 feet of the target property",
}

function applyRank(rank) {
  let elem = document.querySelector('#proposed-rank');
  //  elem.innerText = RANK_TO_DESCRIPTION_MAPPING[rank]; // remove this if you don't want the text changed.
  elem.classList.remove('R', 'B', 'Y', 'G');
  elem.classList.add(rank);
}

// this is how to use the function
// applyRank('R');
// or applyRank('B');
// or applyRank('Y');
// or applyRank('G');

// this part not neccesary
//setInterval(() => applyRank(['Y', 'B', 'R', 'G'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]), 1000);
```

```css
.R {
  color: red;
}

.G {
  color: green;
}

.B {
  color: blue;
}

.Y {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-light">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> Rank: </th>
      <td id="proposed-rank"> Click the buttons to change the rank </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="applyRank('R')">Rank R</button>
<button onclick="applyRank('Y')">Rank Y</button>
<button onclick="applyRank('G')">Rank G</button>
<button onclick="applyRank('B')">Rank B</button>
```

Comment: Hi Kinglish, It is only supplying the first color in my list.  It will not apply the other colors.  Plus is there a way to only apply the rank and not the description?  Other than that it works.  I am getting closer to success.

Comment: I revised my answer to show how NOT to change the text, and how to use it for all 4 colors. The css part is very important too.

Comment: Kinglish,  I can only get it to show one color for all the Ranks.  I try to add the or   but then nothing works.  been trying to find a way to fix this issue but so far no luck. 
 applyRank('R');
 or applyRank('B');
 or applyRank('Y');
 or applyRank('G');

Comment: Ok, check it out now> I've shown how to use buttons to change the rank. But I might be misunderstanding how you're implementing this - at which point in your code do you need to decide the rank?

Comment: Kinglish  I will try to explain better.  I do  a search by address in a search bar and it gives me a report with the address  longitude and latitude of the address according to mapbox.  Then we Rank the Address with letter and a Description according to environmental factors.  So depending on the address the Rank could be R, Y, G, B .  So all I want to do is color the Rank  R would be red, Y, would be yellow or yellowgreen color, G would be green and B would be Blue.   And all Descriptions would stay Black Text for now or if it is easier I could color code those to.

Comment: @scott - how do you populate your search results? Through ajax? Can I see the code you use to rank the address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233340/discussion-between-scott-and-kinglish).

Comment: @Scott - I don't mean to badger you, but I did spend time, including chatting in real time to make sure your issue got resolved. It's a small thing for you to acknowledge that by accepting this as the answer and perhaps an upvote for the extra mile. A small thing for you, but a meaningful one for me.

Comment: I get it I really appreciate the help in getting this working.  I was just doing some testing of the fix and figuring out where to check the fix to give you the credit you deserve.